# Is Northern Cyprus the only EU territory under foreign occupation?

Tags: european-union, turkey, cyprus, northern-cyprus

Northern Cyprus is a territory in Cyprus that is occupied by Turkey, according to everyone except Turkey. Cyprus is part of the EU, which makes Northern Cyprus an EU territory under foreign occupation.

Is there any other EU country that has some of its territory occupied by another country, whether that other country is an EU member or not? Or is Northern Cyprus the only such case?

Comment: Meh, this is debatable: Gibraltar is no longer in the EU, IIRC. Spain clams it's occupied territory by the UK. There might be other examples.

Comment: I mean, there are absolutely people in Catalonia, Brittany, Basque Country, Bavaria and who knows where else who would certainly say that those regions are being occupied by foreign powers. Whether you believe them is another question. There are anti-EU people who say that the European Union itself is a foreign government that controls their country, for that matter.

Comment: But Catalonia. Brittany, Basque country and Bavaria are not EU member states, and so this question doesn't apply to their territory unless that territory is considered to belong to Spain, France and Germany.

Comment: @MikeScott Northern Cyprus isn't more of a EU member state than Catalonia. Either you consider its de jure status as a part of the Republic of Cyprus, which means it isn't a member state, only a part of one; or you consider its de facto status as the independent Turkish Republic of Northern Cyprus, which isn't a member state either.

Comment: @AmiralPatate Cyprus is an EU member state, and part of its territory is occupied by Northern Cyprus. Since France, Spain and Germany have control of Brittany, Basque country, Catalonia and Bavaria, the situations aren’t analogous — in none of those cases has the EU member lost control of any of its claimed territory.

Comment: The Federal Republic of Germany claimed the territory of the German Democratic Republic until 1970. That was before the EU but it overlaps with the beginnings of what became known as the EC, the EU's predecessor.

Comment: Denmark had a [border dispute with Canada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Island) until recently.  But even before the resolution, you couldn't really call the territory "occupied" by either side;  they just left [passive-agressive notes & gifts for each other.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisky_War)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Gibraltar has already been mentioned in the comments.

France does not have effective control of the area around the Maroni river in French Guiana, including territory which is also claimed by Suriname since the border in that area is disputed. However Suriname doesn't control that area either. [Note: the border dispute was resolved in 2021. See comments.]

Ireland only renounced its territorial claim on Northern Ireland in 1999 — until that time, its claimed territory was occupied by the UK (and of course still is, but it's no longer claimed by Ireland).

Rockall in the North Atlantic is claimed and most recently occupied by the UK. Ireland does not recognise that claim, but has not made a claim of its own.

The Treaty of Vienna in 1815 awarded the town of Olivenza and the surrounding area to Portugal, but Spain never complied. I do not believe that Portugal is actively pursuing the claim, but it has not renounced it.

There are several unresolved border disputes between the countries that used to be part of Yuogoslavia, including EU members Slovenia and Croatia.

Comment: Germany and the Netherlands have an unresolved river border. They agreed on practical administrative matters while neither side abandons their claim.

Comment: The dispute about the border between Surinam and France has been pacifically resolved in 2021: http://geoconfluences.ens-lyon.fr/actualites/veille/breves/trace-frontiere-france-suriname

Comment: There's a Wikipedia article on [Croatia–Serbia border dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croatia%E2%80%93Serbia_border_dispute)

Comment: I believe that there are still some disputes between the UK and Ireland as to the exact location of the maritime border in Carlingford Lough (and perhaps also Lough Foyle).

Comment: The water borders between Austria, Germany and Switzerland through Lake Constance are also disputed. The word "occupy" doesn't make much sense in the context of disputed river or lake borders though.

Comment: More specifically; Ireland does not recognize the claim to territorial water around Rockall, citing it being uninhabitable.

Comment: @Joshua Which is why someone inhabited it for over a month in 1985, making a claim of uninhabitability difficult to sustain.

Comment: @MikeScott: I can channel Ireland's arguments if you want, but what's the point? I have no dog in this fight.

Answer (score 2):

80% of the territory of **Western Sahara** is occupied and administered by Morocco. Western Sahara is arguably part of a EU member state, despite Spain formally renouncing its rights and obligations over its former colony in February 1976 (see [Madrid Accords](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madrid_Accords)), the United Nations considers Spain to be the *de jure* administering power (see [Letter addressed to the President of the Security Council](https://digitallibrary.un.org/record/458183?ln=es)). The Madrid Agreement did not transfer sovereignty over Western Sahara, nor did it confer upon any of the signatories the status of an administering Power, a status which Spain alone could not have unilaterally transferred.

Comment: Well... I'm not sure it's occupation when the supposed rightful holder of the land is not interested in it. But thanks for that tidbit.

Comment: Maybe it is not an occupation of an EU territory, but it is certainly an occupation of the sahrawi territory.